# How to bulkify the code, I am facing Too many SOQL queries

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, bulkification

The most common error any developer faces is Too Many SOQL queries while working on Trigger. In this code I am facing Too many DML on line AggregateResult.

```
trigger DrawingSharing on Drawing__c (after insert, after update) { 
    if(trigger.isInsert){ 
        List<Drawing__c> lstDrawing = new List<Drawing__c>();
        for (Drawing__c eachDrawing : Trigger.new){
            lstDrawing.add(eachDrawing);
        }
        //<---------------Creating Installation Record with each Installation Activity added on Drawing--------------------->
        List<Installation__c> lstInstalltion = new List <Installation__c>();
        for(Drawing__c eachDrawing :lstDrawing){
            for(String installationActivityList :eachDrawing.Installation_Activity__c.split(';')){
                if(installationActivityList != null){
                    if(installationActivityList != 'N/A'){
                        Installation__c inst = new Installation__c();
                        inst.Drawing_ID__c = eachDrawing.Id;
                        inst.Installation_Activity__c=installationActivityList;
                        inst.Execution__c=eachDrawing.Execution_ID__c;
                        inst.Floor__c=eachDrawing.Floors__c;
                        inst.Type_of_Package__c= eachDrawing.Type_of_Package__c;
                        lstInstalltion.add(inst);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
        if(lstInstalltion.size() > 0){
            insert lstInstalltion;   
        }
         //<---------------Creating Drawing Checklist Record with each EIR added on Drawing--------------------->
        List<Drawing_Checklist__c> lstDrawingChecklist = new List <Drawing_Checklist__c>();
        for(Drawing__c eachDrawing :lstDrawing){
            for(String EIRCheckList :eachDrawing.EIR_Checklist__c.split(';')){
                if(EIRCheckList != null){
                    if(EIRCheckList != 'N/A'){
                    Drawing_Checklist__c DChecklist = new Drawing_Checklist__c();
                    DChecklist.Drawing_Name__c = eachDrawing.Id;
                    DChecklist.EIR_Checklist__c=EIRCheckList;
                    DChecklist.Execution_ID__c=eachDrawing.Execution_ID__c;
                    DChecklist.Floor__c=eachDrawing.Floors__c;
                    lstDrawingChecklist.add(DChecklist);
                }
            }
        }
     }
       if(lstDrawingChecklist.size() > 0){
            insert lstDrawingChecklist;   
        }
        
        //<-----------Sharing Of Access on Drawing Records ------------------------->
        Map <Id,Id> DrawingProjectMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        Map<Id,Drawing__c> drawingIdObjMap = new Map<Id,Drawing__c>([select id, name,Approver__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c from Drawing__c where id in :lstDrawing]);
        for(Drawing__c Drawing : drawingIdObjMap.values())
        { 
            DrawingProjectMap.put(Drawing.Id,Drawing.Execution_ID__r.Project__c);
            system.debug('Drawing' + Drawing);
        }
        system.debug(DrawingProjectMap);
        system.debug('drawingIdObjMap.keyset()'+ drawingIdObjMap.keyset());
        system.debug('drawingIdObjMap.values()'+ drawingIdObjMap.values());
        
        Map<Id,RoleObjectSharing__mdt> roleobjaccessmap = new Map<Id,RoleObjectSharing__mdt>([select id,Object__c,role__c,Accesslevel__c from RoleObjectSharing__mdt where Object__c='Drawing']);
        Map<String,String> RoleAccessmap = new Map<String,String>(); 
        for(RoleObjectSharing__mdt Robj : roleobjaccessmap.values()){
            RoleAccessmap.put(Robj.role__c,Robj.Accesslevel__c);   
        }
        system.debug(RoleAccessmap.keySet());
        system.debug(DrawingProjectMap.values());           
        Map<Id,Projects__c> teamrolemap = new Map<Id,Projects__c>([select Id,(select id, User_Lookup__c,Role__c from TeamRoles__r where Role__c in:RoleAccessmap.keySet()) from Projects__c where Id in :DrawingProjectMap.values()]);
        system.debug('teamrolemap'+teamrolemap);
        List <Drawing__Share> DrawShareList = new List<Drawing__Share>();
        INTEGER countFound = 0;
        for(Drawing__c drawobj : lstDrawing){                                                         
            Projects__c proj = teamrolemap.get(DrawingProjectMap.get(drawobj.id));
            system.debug(proj.teamroles__r);
            for(teamroles__c tr : proj.teamroles__r){
                system.debug(tr);
                if(tr.Role__c == 'PlanningEngineer' || tr.Role__c == 'AssistantPlanningEngineer' || tr.Role__c == 'PlanningManager' || tr.Role__c == 'AssistantPlanningManager' && countFound <=0) {
                    countFound = countFound + 1;
                    Drawing__c ddd = drawingIdObjMap.get(drawobj.Id);
                    ddd.Approver__c = tr.User_Lookup__c;
                    update ddd;
                }     
                Drawing__Share recruiterShr = new Drawing__Share();
                recruiterShr.ParentId = drawobj.Id;   
                recruiterShr.UserOrGroupId = tr.User_Lookup__c;
                recruiterShr.AccessLevel = RoleAccessmap.get(tr.role__c);
                recruiterShr.RowCause = tr.role__c+'__c';
                DrawShareList.add(recruiterShr);
            }
            system.debug(DrawShareList);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(DrawShareList,false);
        Integer i=0;
        for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
        } 
    }
    //<----------------- Updates of Counts on Execution and Projects ------------------------------->
    if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){ 
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw1 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw2 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw3 = new List<Execution__c>();
        List<Execution__c> updateExecutionDraw4 = new List<Execution__c>();
        
        List<Projects__c> updateProjectsDraw1 = new List<Projects__c>();
        List<Projects__c> updateProjectsDraw2 = new List<Projects__c>();
        List<Projects__c> updateProjectsDraw3 = new List<Projects__c>();
        
        
        
        //<------------ Update Number of Shop Drawing Quantified on Execution from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Shop_Quantification_Completed__c = true GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawing_Quantified__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawing_Quantified__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw1.add(updateMe);
        }
        
        //<------------ Update Number of GFC Drawing Quantified on Execution from Drawing---------------------->
       /* for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE GFC_Quantification_Completed__c = true GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_GFC_Drawing_Quantified__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_GFC_Drawing_Quantified__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw2.add(updateMe);
        }*/
        
        //<------------ Update Number of As Built Drawings Approved on Execution & Project from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE As_built_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Approved with Comments') GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_As_Built_Drawings_Approved__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_As_Built_Drawings_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw3.add(updateMe);
            
            Projects__c updateProj = new Projects__c();
            updateProj.Id = (String)count1.get('Project__c');
            updateProj.As_Built_Drawing_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateProjectsDraw1.add(updateProj);
        }
        
        //<------------ Update Shop Drawing Approved on Execution & Project from Drawing---------------------->
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), max(Shop_Drawing_Approved_by_Client_on__c), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Shop_Drawing_Client_Approval_Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Approved with Comments') GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
            updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
            // updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawings_Approved__c = 0;
            updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawings_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateExecutionDraw4.add(updateMe);
            
            Projects__c updateProj = new Projects__c();
            updateProj.Id = (String)count1.get('Project__c');
            updateProj.Shop_Drawing_Approved__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateProj.Latest_Drawing_Approved_Date__c = (Date)count1.get('expr1');
            updateProjectsDraw2.add(updateProj);
        }
        
        for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c FROM Drawing__c GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
            // |DEBUG| AggregateResult count1: AggregateResult:{expr0=1, Execution_ID__c=a1L5D0000017R4yUAE}
            System.debug('Check each AggregateResult count1: '+count1);
            
            Projects__c updateProj = new Projects__c();
            updateProj.Id = (String)count1.get('Project__c');
            updateProj.Number_of_Drawings__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
            updateProjectsDraw3.add(updateProj);
        }
        
        update updateExecutionDraw1;
        update updateExecutionDraw2;
        update updateExecutionDraw3;
        update updateExecutionDraw4;
        update updateProjectsDraw1;
        update updateProjectsDraw2;
        update updateProjectsDraw3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. There's no way I could help you fix them all in one question.

However, I can give you some general tips.

1. Try using a trigger framework. This will enable you to break your code up into smaller more easily testable pieces.
2. SOQL in for loops is a huge no-no. Remove them, typically by storing the result of whatever you are doing in the loop, in a list variable.
3. Break your code into smaller pieces and try to do some of it using async means (`Queueable`, `@future`)
4. Try to use repeatable methods to do the work. Each method should do one thing and return an object to the caller. Each method should have no external dependencies other than what you pass in (if possible)
5. No need to check if a list if empty before calling insert. Remove this:

   ```
   if(lstInstalltion.size() > 0){
       insert lstInstalltion;   
   }
   //Replace with:
   insert lstInstalltion;
   ```
6. Where possible and practical, combine your update lists into one.
7. Your code is not bulkified and appears to handle only one trigger sObject at a time. Ultimately, this is not going to work.

Your code lends itself to a series of `@future` methods. Eg:

```
@future
public static updateQuantifiedShopDrawingCount(Set<Id> executionIds){
    List<Execution__c> executionsToUpdate = new List<Execution__c>();
    for(AggregateResult count1 : [SELECT COUNT(Id), Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c 
                                  FROM Drawing__c 
                                  WHERE Shop_Quantification_Completed__c = true 
                                  GROUP BY Execution_ID__c, Execution_ID__r.Project__c 
                                  HAVING Execution_ID__c = :Trigger.New[0].Execution_ID__c]){
        Execution__c updateMe = new Execution__c();
        updateMe.Id = (String)count1.get('Execution_ID__c');
        updateMe.Number_of_Shop_Drawing_Quantified__c = (Decimal)count1.get('expr0');
        executionsToUpdate.add(updateMe);
    }
    update executionsToUpdate;
}
```

You'd just pass in all the execution ids you received from the trigger.

Comment: yes it worked. I converted my Trigger  into Handler and used future method. Thank You